# reactjs display user info from passportjs auth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

im using passport to authenticate in the server of my react boilerplate application but I'm not sure how to get req.user from my server side to reactjs...

Should I change this

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html'), (err, file) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
      } else {
        res.send(file.toString());
      }
    });
  });
```

I'm very unsure how to do this especially because I have not used reactjs before

Comment: Are you using `body-parser` library ?

Comment: in server side i am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a route(before the code you sent) to retrieve it, like this:

```
app.get('/userDetails', (req, res) => res.json(req.user))
```

And a warning: your user object has probably some fields you shouldn't send to the client, so it would be good to delete them before sending a response:

```
app.get('/userDetails', (req, res) => {
  const { user } = req.body
  delete user.password
  res.json(user)
})
```

Then you need to fetch the data by doing a request to the backend. One possible implementation would be:

```
class SomeComponent {
  state = { user: null }
  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('/userDetails')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(user => {
      // do something with the data
      console.log(user)
      this.setState({ user })
    })
  render () {
    const { user } = this.state
    return (
      <span>{user ? user.firstName : 'No user data'}</span>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this, and no password im using oauth

Comment: How do i access these userdetails in reactjs now?

Comment: @strykes i also added some react code for you showing how you can retrieve that data on client

Comment: Basically, in this case the app is split in 2 parts: backend, interacting with the DB and serving the data through a JSON API, and a react client app, which then uses the backend API to retrieve the necessary data.

Comment: FWIW you don't *need* to make a separate API call (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [templating engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) embedding data into views is pretty straightforward.

Here's an example using pug:

**views/index.pug**

```
doctype html
html
    body
        h2 Page
        script.
            window.user = '#{JSON.stringify(user)}'
```

**server.js**

```
app.use('view engine', 'pug');
...
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
         user: {
             id: 1,
             name: 'Joe Bloggs'
             ...
         }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I'm using react.js

Comment: Could you modify it to work with my app.get in my original post?

Comment: @strykes I've given you an example of how you can use it with your default route (at least using pug). There are other templating engines too, if your unsure about how they work I suggest you read the docs to understand them. To summarise, you'd need to convert your index.html over to index.pug